# Prefixing Magento URL with Locality (htaccess/URL rewriting)

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting, url-routing

So I'm setting up a Magento installation off the back of a WordPress installation; so at:

- root.level/ is WordPress
- root.level/shop/ is Magento

All elements of the website, *except* the catalogue are being handled through WordPress. Magento *only* deals with the catalogue.

The website is to be completely localised for the UK, rest of Europe and US markets. On WordPress, I've achieved this effectively using the qTranslate plugin, so all the following are working:

- root.level/uk/
- root.level/eu/
- root.level/us/

In Magento, I've created 3 storefronts and using the configuration I've managed to make them appear as:

- root.level/shop/uk/
- root.level/shop/eu/
- root.level/shop/us/

However, for consistency I would prefer for the 1st URL segment to *always* represent the locality. I have therefore written the following to the root (WordPress installation) htaccess:

```
#shop moves
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/shop/(.*)[/]{0,1}$ /shop/index.php?___store=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/shop[/]{0,1}$ /shop/index.php?___store=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which has the desired effect in so much as root.level/uk/shop/ will load up the UK magento storefront homepage, and root.level/uk/shop/xyz.html has the desired behavior. The problem is that the links on the store page are still pointing to root.level/shop/xyz.html. How do I go about making the links reflect the rewritten URLs?

I've tried going in to Magento *Admin-->System-->Config*, setting the scope to the relevant store front then under *Web* changing the "Link URL" (under both *Secure* and *Insecure*) and while this corrects the links it makes every page 404 (including the homepage) on that storefront. Is there somewhere I need to edit Magento's URL reading behavior?

Edit:
So this is weird. I've got it working on /eu/shop/ and /us/shop/ but /uk/shop/ is still returning 404s. I thought it was because the UK was set to default but changing that doesn't seem to affect things. Any ideas?

Comment: OK this is weird.

/eu/shop/ and /us/shop/ both now work

/uk/shop/ (the default) doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `.htaccess` to get it work :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Redirect old /shop/uk/ to new /uk/shop
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/shop/([a-z]{2})(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1/shop/%2 [R=302,L]

  # Load the right file for new /uk/shop
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/shop/(.*)/?$ /shop/index.php?___store=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/shop/?$      /shop/index.php?___store=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately it has the exact same result as above - with the LINK URL set as default, all the shop links are still /shop/uk/; with the LINK URL set as root.level/uk/shop/ I get 404s.